# can not save hdc to a bitmap correctly

Tags: winapi, bitmap, gdi

I tried to save a memory DC to a bitmap file. But I can not get the right value about size for the following:

```
infoHeader.biSizeImage

fileHeader.bfSize


fileHeader.bfOffBits

WriteFile(hFile, &fileHeader, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), &dwBytesWritten, NULL);

WriteFile(hFile, &infoHeader, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), &dwBytesWritten, NULL);

WriteFile(hFile, pPixels, info.bmiHeader.biSizeImage, &dwBytesWritten, NULL);
```

I can get a file, but I can not open it, since it complains that it is broken or it is no longer supported.

There are many source about saving to bmp, but many of them have different value for the size.
Some also include Palette information. I am totoally confused.

Could someone indicate how to fill the correct information?

```
static void SaveAsBmp(TCHAR *fileName)
{
HDC hdcView = GetDC(hwndView);
HDC memDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcView);

RECT rcView;
GetClientRect(hwndView, &rcView);

int rcView_dx = rcView.right - rcView.left;
int rcView_dy = rcView.bottom - rcView.top;

HBITMAP hMemBmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcView, rcView_dx, rcView_dy);
HBITMAP hOldBmp = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(memDC, hMemBmp);

BitBlt(memDC, 0, 0, rcView_dx, rcView_dy, hdcView, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

//----------

BITMAP bmp;
GetObject(hMemBmp, sizeof(BITMAP), &bmp);

//----------

WORD wBits = (WORD)(bmp.bmBitsPixel * bmp.bmPlanes);

if(wBits <=  1)                                                   
    wBits = 1;             
else  if(wBits <=  4)                               
    wBits  = 4;             
else if(wBits <=  8)                               
    wBits  = 8;             
else if (wBits <= 16)
    wBits = 16;
else if (wBits <= 24)
    wBits = 24;
else wBits = 32; 

//----------

BITMAPINFOHEADER infoHeader;
BITMAPINFO info;
info.bmiHeader = infoHeader;

infoHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);    
infoHeader.biWidth = bmp.bmWidth; 
infoHeader.biHeight = bmp.bmHeight;    
infoHeader.biPlanes = bmp.bmPlanes;    
infoHeader.biBitCount = bmp.bmBitsPixel;     
infoHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;   

infoHeader.biSizeImage = 2 * ((bmp.bmWidth * bmp.bmBitsPixel + 15) / 16)  * bmp.bmPlanes * bmp.bmHeight;
infoHeader.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;  
infoHeader.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
infoHeader.biClrUsed = 0;
infoHeader.biClrImportant = 0;

RGBQUAD *pPixels = new RGBQUAD[bmp.bmWidth * bmp.bmWidth]; 
GetDIBits(memDC, hMemBmp, 0, bmp.bmWidth, pPixels, &info, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

BITMAPFILEHEADER fileHeader;
fileHeader.bfType = 0x4d42;
fileHeader.bfSize = (DWORD)(sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) + info.bmiHeader.biSizeImage);
fileHeader.bfReserved1 = 0;
fileHeader.bfReserved2 = 0;
fileHeader.bfOffBits = (DWORD)(sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + info.bmiHeader.biSize);

HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(fileName, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

DWORD dwBytesWritten;

WriteFile(hFile, &fileHeader, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), &dwBytesWritten, NULL);
WriteFile(hFile, &infoHeader, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), &dwBytesWritten, NULL);
WriteFile(hFile, pPixels, info.bmiHeader.biSizeImage, &dwBytesWritten, NULL);

CloseHandle(hFile);

delete pPixels;

SelectObject(memDC, hOldBmp);
DeleteObject(hMemBmp);
DeleteDC(memDC);
```

Answer (score 0):

> infoHeader.biSizeImage = 2 * ((bmp.bmWidth * bmp.bmBitsPixel + 15) / 16)  * bmp.bmPlanes * bmp.bmHeight;

does not look right here, it should be `bmp.bmBitsPixel >> 3`, assuming it is 24 or 32. That is, it's bits per pixel and you are using it as if it were bytes per pixel.

The code in general looks good and you should rather inspect the variables with debugger to find mismatches (or paste them here, esp. `BITMAPINFOHEADER`).

Note also, that you might have done it in a bit different way: instead of using `CreateCompatibleBitmap`, you could use `CreateDIBSection` with format of your interest, such as 24 bpp RGB, for which you would immediately receive raw pointer to bits. Then blitting data into this bitmap you don't need `GetObject` call anymore since you already have everything you need. And, `GetObject` might return you `DIBSECTION` format with already ready to use `BITMAPINFOHEADER`. It is all the same, just simpler.

Comment: Finally, use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145119%28v=vs.85%29.aspx, it works